# Is it safe to disable Network Location process?

Tags: processes, location-services, disable-app

I only use GPS in case of navigation and not the others methods(determine location using wireless networks); so is it safe that I disable 'Network Location' process? this process spawn three other processes named:

```
com.google.process.gapps
com.google.process.location
com.google.android.gms.persistent
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to completely disable or limit the wake locks using Amplify?

Comment: actually my reason is that I don't use navigation based on network location and this process also uses nearly 50mb of ram. so it seems there's no use for it to run. If it doesn't break my phone, I want to completely disable it

Comment: Android version and  phone?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 GT-S7272 (rooted) android 4.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving network location enabled will save battery power, and in some cases increase location accuracy (especially when you have a weak or no GPS signal).

If you disable network location but leave GPS location you can still use the location services of your device. However, there is no guarantee that *every* app will work perfectly (some may crash, but probably shouldn't), and you may get a less accurate location or get drops in the location service's ability to provide a location.

But generally it is "safe" in that you can still use location services without it.